# Fetch Selected code from a HTML file and store in an PHP array

Tags: php, javascript, html, curl

I am having a HTML file containing Javascript code:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var statList = new Array(
0, "192.168.1.179", "88-53-95-28-2B-AF", 194280, 101141053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, "192.168.1.170", "60-C5-47-10-37-FD", 132316, 65860791, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, "192.168.1.151", "68-5D-43-21-76-95", 9887, 3898646, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
3, "192.168.1.134", "6C-3E-6D-8C-FF-62", 26405, 7521875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
4, "192.168.1.124", "04-F7-E4-78-D3-D0", 6189, 1791672, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
5, "192.168.1.121", "60-C5-47-10-40-92", 122657, 91113301, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
</SCRIPT>
```

I want to get the contents from this file. Here is an array in javascript that is "StatList". I want to select all the IP addresses like (192.168.1.179) in an array and all Mac Addresses like(88-53-95-28-2B-AF) in another PHP array.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Yes, but that's a javascript array. You need to pass it with AJAX to PHP first

Comment: How can I do it ? Can you please help ?

Comment: After you look over the following, come back with what you tried  https://www.google.ro/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ajax+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=RI4LUZHqPMTQtAb1pIHIBA http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the HTML as a string you can scrape it with a regular expression like this:

```
<?php

    $html = '<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var statList = new Array(
    0, "192.168.1.179", "88-53-95-28-2B-AF", 194280, 101141053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, "192.168.1.170", "60-C5-47-10-37-FD", 132316, 65860791, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    2, "192.168.1.151", "68-5D-43-21-76-95", 9887, 3898646, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    3, "192.168.1.134", "6C-3E-6D-8C-FF-62", 26405, 7521875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    4, "192.168.1.124", "04-F7-E4-78-D3-D0", 6189, 1791672, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    5, "192.168.1.121", "60-C5-47-10-40-92", 122657, 91113301, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    </SCRIPT>';
    $regex = '/\d+,\s+"(?P<ip>[\d\.]+)",\s+"(?P<mac>[\-\dA-F]+)",/';

    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches['ip']);
    print_r($matches['mac']);

?>
```

[working example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ksf-mt9)